# Is it possible to publish a site without its comments in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, production-environment

I am only just starting to program and in my code I have a lot of silly comments (`<!-- comment -->`) that are really only meant for myself. For example lots of links to stackoverflow articles to understand my own code as well as explanations to myself why I wrote the code the way I did.

This code is included in views (html) as well as server-side code (e.g., controller and model files).

For a visitor of my website these comments might look silly and amateuristic. So if they'd visit my website and looked at the source code I would like to not have those comments included.

**Is there a way to publish a site without its comments in production?** (while keeping the comments in development)

I am using Rails4 and Heroku.

**Update:** I understand now that comments in model and controller files won't be visible to visitors of my web page, anyway. So then it only concerns the comments in my view pages (.html.erb), i.e., embedded html comments in your webpages. It could also concern Javascript, but currently my website hardly contains any of that. Does anyone have an example of a script for removing these comments when pushing to production/heroku?

Comment: Are you talking about server-side code or client-side code?

Comment: It would be good if you clarified where your comments are and what you mean by `visitor`.

Comment: For server side code, i.e the rails code, visitors won't be able to see that code anyway so there is no point removing comments. For client side JS, you can minify it.

Comment: If I understand the differences between server-side code and client-side code correctly, the html in my view pages in Rails would be considered client-side code and model files etc. server-side code. If this is correct then I would say the answer is both. The purpose is that a visitor of my website cannot read any of the comments when s/he visits my website and looks at the source-code. I have these kinds of comments in server-side code as well as in client-side code but I also understand that for server-side code it is already not possible to see these comments for visitors of my website.

Comment: So my question seems to particularly apply to client side Ruby/html

Comment: So what you're saying is you embedded html comments in your webpages. You could always write a script that removes those comments and saves them as different files then when you deploy tell your installer or whatever you use to run the script and take the copies instead of the originals

Comment: You can remove comments in javascript code by configuring uglifier which is javacript compressor with asset pipeline in Rails https://github.com/lautis/uglifier.

Comment: There is no client-side Ruby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to omit html comments from the source code, you can convert your html comments to erb comments as erb comments wont get rendered to the markup

so convert your html comments:

```
<!-- comment -->
```

to erb comments:

```
<%# comment %>
```

its a little hacky, but it should work for you. this will keep the comments in your code base viewable from the editor or github, but will omit them from being visible from the client (in any environment, not just production)